# VS Code Dev Containers and Corporate Proxies

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy, omnisharp, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying to run the VS Code .NET 5.0 dev container behind a corporate proxy (on a VPN). Sadly, every time I start the container I fail to download/install the OmniSharp extensions.

Here's what I get:

```sh
Installing C# dependencies...
Platform: linux, x86_64, name=ubuntu, version=20.04

Downloading package 'OmniSharp for Linux (x64)'     Retrying from 'https://roslynomnisharp.blob.core.windows.net/releases/1.37.10/omnisharp-linux-x64-1.37.10.zip' Failed at stage: downloadPackage
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Specifically, I have a copy of zscaler running locally on `localhost:9000`.  I can download the link for the OmniSharp package directly (in chrome) without issues. I tried adding the proxy URLs to the dev container Dockerfile, but with no success.

```
ENV HTTPS_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:9000/localproxy.pac"
ENV HTTP_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:9000/localproxy.pac"
```

Docker claims to be using the WSL subsystem, and from within an Ubuntu container I can access the outside world fine, so I'm not sure what to try next.  Any ideas?